# What is the correct preposition? (And is there one?)

Tags: soft-question, terminology, euclidean-geometry, mathematical-writing

I just stumbled upon a linguistic problem I wasn't able to resolve via web search. Suppose we're given some geometric set $A$ and subset $B\subset A$. Isn't there a compact way of saying that there exists, say, a plane whose intersection with $A$ is equal to $B$ of the form "there exists a plane intersecting $A$ (preposition) $B$"?

AFAICT, the prepositions "at", "by" and "along" do not fit in general. Maybe I refuse to accept that there is no such construction in English because I'm just too used to the analogous Russian expression.

Comment: I use "in" for this.

Comment: Hmm... It seemed somehow off to me before. But now that you've mentioned it, it actually seems to be the one! =)

Comment: I'd agree that "in" is correct, but potentially misread. Changing the quoted phrase in the question to "there exists a plane whose intersection with A is B" is unambiguous and scarcely longer than the more ambiguous.

Comment: Although I use "in" for this all the time in conversations, I completely agree with @paulgarrett that for formal writing --- where there's no opportunity for the reader to ask for clarification --- it's much better to find a completely unambiguous construction.

Comment: It doesn't take too much remodeling to make this unambiguous: there exists a plane whose intersection with A *is* B.

Comment: @IgorMakhlin, what is the corresponding Russian expression you are thinking of: существует плоскость, пересечение которого с A является B? There's no preposition in front of B there.

Comment: @KConrad плоскость, пересекающая А *по* В. Which is perfectly unambiguous, to me at least.

Comment: @others Actually, even before I posted this question I settled for the "is"-version in the text I was writing and I won't be changing it either. I went with "is equal to" here just to accentuate my point.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer to your question is *no*---at least modulo any errors in the [classification of English prepositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions) given on wikipedia (which classification includes *modulo*, by the way). There are a number that almost work and others that might make you smile but none that really do the job right.

Comment: It's missing a very important preposition because prescriptivism.